# Where do I plug in the cdrom connection to the motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, compact-disc

I have a gigabyte ex58 ud4p motherboard.

Can someone help me find where I plug it into the motherboard too?

The board is here: http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Support/Motherboard/Manual_Model.aspx?ProductID=2986#anchor_os

**UPdate**
I have a LG super multi dvd (its 22x).
The end of the cord says serial ATA.

Comment: Do you have an IDE or SATA CD-ROM/DVD-ROM drive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you have an IDE CD/DVD drive then you would Plug the unit into the IDE connector noted in the following picture.  If your cd rom drive is SATA then it would connect to one of the numerous SATA connectors on the border of the mainboard.

[image: Mainboard Image]

Comment: Don't be fooled by the CD_IN connector to the lower left! That's only used for computers built in 1996.

Comment: I thought that was for audio CDs?

Comment: @EMDD  you are correct. that is indeed the CD audio line in.

Comment: The end of the cable says serial ATA, so do I need a IDE adapter plug?

Comment: You should be able to use the SATA connector to hook the drive up.  That connector is right next to the Bios battery on the mainboard.